# How to Determine the number of integer/natural solutions of:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

How i can determine the number of integer solutions of:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\:=\:35 $$
$$\:8\ge x_1\:\ge 3\space\:\:x_2\ge 0\space\:\:x_3\ge\:0\space\:\:\:x_4\ge \:\:0\:\:\:\:x_5\ge \:\:0$$

How i can determine the number of natural solutions of:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\:=\:35 $$
$$\:7\ge \:x_1\:\ge \:3\space\space\:\:8\ge\:x_2\:\ge\:0\:\space\:\:x_3\ge \:0\space\:\:\:x_4\ge 0\:\:\:\:x_5\ge 0$$

Comment: What have you tried? If you do show us your work, we are not going to help you out. Also please take care from next time asking only one question, not multiple questions together.

Comment: @Anonymous, I don't how to solve it when i have 8 ≥ x1 ≥ 3 with lower bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these type of questions you can use the following techniques:

If $3 \leq x_1 \leq8$ ,then you can say that $0 \leq x_1 \leq5$ ,so the sum will be $32$ instead of $35$ because we should subtract $3$ from both sides.

Then ,the question turned out to be combination with repetition :$C(32+5-1,32)$

However , $x_1$ should not be greater that $5$ , so we should subtract the situation where $x_1$ is greater than $5$ from the total result (by principle of inclusion-exclusion ).This can be done by :

If $x_1 \geq 6$ ,then by using same technique , we should substract $6$ from the total ; so

$C(32+5-1,32)- C(26+5-1,26)=$ Desired result..

The second can be solved the same technique but there is two restriction ,so when you use inclusion-exclusion , pay attention it !

NOTE: You can use also generating functions to solve it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have a doubt about how to write a combination with repetition ": C (32 + 5−1.32)". What is n and what is m? See image [link](https://i.ibb.co/XZvjfMx/CR.webp) please, thanks

Comment: @casioman $m=5 , n=32 $ in your picture.

Comment: Thanks @bulbasaur. Sorry to bother you, i have one more doubt. Where did you get 1,32 and 1,26, and why it's subtracting on C(32+5−1,32)?

Comment: @casioman i think , i explained it above.. We get $32$ because , we want to start the restriction of $x_1$ from zero  ,so we subtract $3$ from both sides. The logic of $26$ is the same.

Comment: @casioman did this answer help you ?